# Intellij keeps creating new test run configurations

Tags: intellij-idea

Every time I try to run a single test (or test class) by right clicking > run or debug, Intellij creates a new run configuration for it, running the same test 3 times gives MyTest, MyTest (1), MyTest (2), etc.

Is there a way to stop it from auto creating these configs and just running the test, or at least create 1 config max? I know I can go to the run config and hit run from there, but I prefer the right click > run method.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, there is.

In settings, section "Advanced Settings", set Temporary Run/Debug configurations limit to 0, as shown:
[IntelliJ IDEA Advanced settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgyTi.png).

Source: [IntelliJ IDEA documentation on Run/debug configurations﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2022.2/run-debug-configuration.html)

> The maximum number of temporary configurations is 5. The older ones are automatically deleted when new ones are added. If necessary, you can increase this limit in Settings/Preferences | Advanced Settings | IDE | Temporary configurations limit.